# Tweepy Stream returning ImportError: cannot import name RE_TYPE

Tags: python, mongodb, tweepy

I was using tweepy to pull tweets and then display them on MongoDB. When I went to rerun it a few days later I am getting  an error.
Mongodb is working fine and RE_TYPE isn't even in my code.

Here is my code:

```
import json
import pymongo
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener


CONSUMER_KEY = 'xxx'#hiding keys
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'xxx'
OAUTH_TOKEN = 'xxx'
OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET = 'xxx'

keyword_list = ['christmas']


class MyStreamListener(StreamListener):
    def __init__(self):
        self.num_tweets = 0  # cpunter starting at 0
        self.tweet_coll = None  # signal that something will go into tweet_coll at some stage

    def mongo_connect(self):
        try:
            client = pymongo.MongoClient()
            print "Mongo is connected!"
            db = client.tech_tweetsDB
            self.tweet_coll = db.tweets
        except pymongo.errors.ConnectionFailure, e:
            print "Could not connect to MongoB: %s" % e

    def on_data(self, data):
        try:
            # read in a tweet
            status = json.loads(data)
            print json.dumps(status, indent=4)
            tweet = {}
            tweet["text"] = status['text'].encode('utf8')  # autf able to read other languages
            tweet['screen_name'] = status['user']['screen_name']
            tweet['followers_count'] = status['user']['followers_count']
            tweet['friends_count'] = status['user']['friends_count']
            tweet['favorite_count'] = status['favorite_count']
            tweet['retweet_count'] = status['retweet_count']
            tweet['created at'] = status['created_at']
            print status.get('entities').get("media")
            if status.get('entities').get("media"):
                print status.get('entities').get("media")
                media = status['entities']["media"]
                tweet['media'] = media[0]["display_url"]
            else:
                tweet['media'] = None

            tweet['lang'] = status['user']['lang']
            tweet['location'] = status['user']['location']

            self.num_tweets += 1
            print self.num_tweets
            if self.num_tweets < 50:
                # Insert tweet in to the collection
                self.tweet_coll.insert(tweet)

                return True
            else:
                return False

            return True
        except BaseException as e:
            print('Failed on_data: %s' % str(e))
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)
        return True


auth = OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)
# api = tweepy.API(auth)
stream = MyStreamListener()
stream.mongo_connect()

twitter_stream = Stream(auth, stream)
twitter_stream.filter(track=keyword_list)
```

My error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 4.5.4\helpers\profiler\run_profiler.py", line 146, in <module>
    profiler.run(file)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 4.5.4\helpers\profiler\run_profiler.py", line 85, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, globals)  # execute the script
  File "C:/Users/Andrew/PycharmProjects/mongoDB/firstMongo.py", line 64, in <module>
    import pymongo
  File "C:\Users\Andrew\flask_test\lib\site-packages\pymongo\__init__.py", line 83, in <module>
    from pymongo.collection import ReturnDocument
  File "C:\Users\Andrew\flask_test\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 34, in <module>
    from pymongo.cursor import Cursor
  File "C:\Users\Andrew\flask_test\lib\site-packages\pymongo\cursor.py", line 22, in <module>
    from bson import RE_TYPE
ImportError: cannot import name RE_TYPE

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This [issue](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PYTHON-472) has been fixed since pymongo 3.2, simply upgrade your package through pip:

```
pip install pymongo --upgrade
```

Comment: Having the same issue unfortunately. Thanks for the response though.

Comment: @AndrewCostello In a worst case scenario uninstall and reinstall it ought to work